# R: transforming vector of objects in a vector of object names

Tags: r, string, loops, object

Context: I am estimating several different specifications with the R package rugarch. Let's say 2 as an example (y is the data):

```
garchmodel<-ugarchspec()
garchfit = ugarchfit(spec=garchmodel, y)
egarchmodel<-ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "eGARCH")
egarchfit<-ugarchfit(spec=egarchmodel, y)
```

I wrote a function to gather the information criteria of the model:

```
CollectInfoCrieria <- function(models){
  infoMat <- t(sapply(models, infocriteria))
  return(infoMat)  
}
```

If I then type

```
themodels = c(garchfit, egarchfit)
CollectInfoCrieria(themodels)
```

I obtain a matrix with the information criteria of each model specification per row. I would like to transform the model names into character strings to use as row names, as I wanted.
If I then define a function

```
getName<-function(names) deparse(substitute(names))
```

Then getName(garchfit) gives "garchfit", while

```
models <- c(garch11fit, egarchfit)
sapply(models, getName)
```

gives
`[1] "X[[i]]" "X[[i]]"`

How can I get

`[1] "garch11fit" "egarchfit"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
garch11fit=1
egarchfit=2
models <- c(garch11fit=garch11fit, egarchfit=egarchfit)
names(models)
```

If you name the variables, you can get their names back. But in your code, the names aren't associated in the models variable, only the values of garch11fit and egarchfit, so you can't get the names back.

Comment: Thanks @Stacker. It's easier than I thought, I don't have to use a function and `sapply`. I still don't understand why `getName(garchfit)` gives `garchfit` without having to name it, but the behaviour is different with a vector of objets and `sapply`

Answer (score 0):

This is how one can collect the object names inside the `CollectInfoCrieria` function:

```
CollectInfoCrieria <- function(...){
  infoMat <- t(sapply(c(...), infocriteria))
  models = as.character(eval(substitute(alist(...))));
  out = data.frame(models,infoMat)
}
```